# Which LightGBM operations should be protected in a multi-threaded environment?

Tags: python, joblib, lightgbm

I am serving predictions from a LightGBM model over gRPC using a Python server process. It is not clear from documentation which parts of LightGBM are thread-safe, and which should be protected by synchronization outside of the module.

The Python gRPC library handles serving requests on different threads. The GIL is a limiting factor for concurrency, but in an I/O intensive server process that is also making heavy use of C code through Numpy and LightGBM there is in practice significant concurrency.

My process has been successfully serving predictions with low loads. When load testing with Locust in preparation to scale up, I am starting to see errors that appear to be caused by different concurrent calls in to LightGBM code.

1. While loading a model persisted using [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.dump.html), segmentation faults can occur:

```
./python.sh: line 13: 23502 Segmentation fault: 11  python "$@"
make: *** [run-server] Error 139
```

2. When the model is successfully loaded and multiple predictions are happening, an OpenMP error regarding thread identifiers occurs:

```
OMP: Error #131: Thread identifier invalid.
OMP: Error #131: Thread identifier invalid.
OMP: Error #131: Thread identifier invalid.
OMP: Error #131: Thread identifier invalid.
./python.sh: line 13: 23533 Abort trap: 6           python "$@"
```

I am intending to load a single LightGBM instance and use Python locks to restrict access so that only a single thread is executing inside the instance at a time. But I was hoping to find more explicit information about which operations are thread-safe and which should be protected. Questions I was hoping for clear answers to:

- Is it safe to load multiple instances in parallel? Perhaps this is a problem with joblib, not LightGBM.
- Once loaded, can a single model instance be executed on different threads simultaneously?
- Once loaded, can a single model instance be used for different predictions

There is a useful [discussion in GitHub issues](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/989), which documents that the predict method is not thread-safe, or at least was not in 2017.